# how do you upload an image and post that image (in production)?

Tags: django

I do it this way, I was told this way isn't the best way to do it in production but this works. And I don't see why I can't use this way that I have to change it.

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
    def get_image_url(self):
        return "%s%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image)
```

Then in template I do it something like this

```
<img src='{{category.get_image_url}}' class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="210" height="200" style="text-align:center;"/>
```

I guess I can use {{category.image}} instead but I don't want to change every thing now...is this a problem?

Comment: Other than having some pointless code that exactly replicates what the imagefield does already, you mean?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, wait what?i mean with the above code I get the images fine but is this a valid way?I wasn't getting any image when I was doing {{category.image}} in local which is why I did it the way I did, but now that I'm in production I don't know if I switch to {{category.image}} from get_image_url

Comment: @DanielRoseman by the way I personally want to thank you for helping me so much, I finally finished my first personal project and you've been so helpful. thank you very much

Comment: Your code seems fine. I don't see why you have to change it. Unless you have to upload three different resolutions of images for purposes like comment photo, profile photo, etc. stuff like that.

Comment: @MiniGunnR, when I was learning django I was told that I shouldn't do it this way in production, but I just did it any way this works fine

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. It would be interesting to know which part of your code is not supposed to be 'used this way' in production?

Comment: @SandervanLeeuwen i was told I shouldn't get image like this; def get_image_url(self):
        return "%s%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image) then get the url

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. Maybe `return "%s%s" % (settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image.url)` would be a little bit 'better'. But there's nothing 'production unsafe' going on.
Bonus: use `format` in favor of `%` formatting. Like: `return '{}{}'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image.url)`

Comment: @SandervanLeeuwen thank you hmm wonder why instructor said that....by the way do you have an experience with elastic beanstalk?do you know how to do python manage.py check_perissions for web that's in production?

Comment: I saw your other question, I don't know anything about elastic beanstalk, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial, maybe this backend code for uploading a file is what you are looking for. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9MDtQHwGYM